# Initialize linked list with linux/list.h

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I am using linux/list.h to work with lists, but I am having trouble getting started.

I having been experimenting with different combinations based on a few guides' recommendations, but nothing has been working so far. Here's what I believe to be my closest attempt at initialization:

```
typedef struct {
    int to;
    struct list_head list;
    int from;
} myFrame;

int main() {
    LIST_HEAD(listInstance);

    myFrame* foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
    list_add(&foo->list, &listInstance);
}
```

This produces the warning

> initializer element is not computable at load time

at LIST_HEAD()

However, [this](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-11-sect-5) seems to indicate that I can.

> Alternatively, lists can be initialized at compile time

Would someone mind helping me wrap my brain around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually want to do:

```
LIST_HEAD(this_is_a_list_instance);
```

You can then do:

```
struct myList *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
foo->to = 3;
foo->from = 4;
list_add(&foo->list, &this_is_a_list_instance);
```

This would also probably be more consistent if you named it `myObject` instead of `myList`.

Comment: So in this case, foo represents a single object in the list? And what sort of parameters will LIST_HEAD() take? I'm not sure what you mean by "this_is_a_list_instance"

Comment: so `LIST_HEAD(this_is_a_list_list_instance)` is a macro that is going to get converted into `struct list_head this_is_a_list_instance = ...`. So I'm using that as a name for an object.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for sticking with me. I have updated my question at the top.

Comment: Fixed by moving LIST_HEAD() outside of main(). Haha, oh well